# Finding birth/baptism record for Owen Melvin B. Pinkerton born in Indiana around 1872

Tags: united-states, birth-records, 18th-century, indiana

My Great Grandfather was Owen Melvin B. Pinkerton born in Indiana around 1872. He was supposedly adopted by the Pinkerton's

Married and had children in Kansas. Wife Florence Munkres. Children Harvey, Edith and Buford.Heard Native Americans killed his birth parents. Adopted by the Pinkerton's. Moved to Washington state maybe in the 1920's.

Where can I find a birth/baptism record for one or both of those events, presumably in Indiana in about 1872?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Please try to ask a single focussed question rather than just posting a broad request for any information.  In this case it seems like you are after a record of his birth so I have edited your question to focus it on that.

Comment: What is your current evidence for Owen having been born in Indiana around 1872?

Comment: What documents have you found so far, census (what years, what states), marriage, death?